# cellforItemAt.... showing sdImage in cell

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, developer-tools

This is my first post. I am completely newbie.
I am trying to show a horizontal scroll View where I would like to display some images in. The matter is in `cellForRowAt` for `CollectionView`, that is in TableView ->

```
cell.imageCollectionList.sd_setImage(with: URL(string:""[indexPath.row].thumbnail), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: ""))
```

I do not know how to create `cell.imageCollectionList`

This is my code:

```
import UIKit
import SDWebImage

class ListViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    var videoArray :[Video] = []

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionListView: UICollectionView!
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        collectionListView.delegate = self
        collectionListView.dataSource = self
        collectionListView.register(UINib(nibName: Constant.VideoIdentifier, bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: Constant.VideoIdentifier)
    
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    }

}

extension ListViewCell: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UICollectionViewDataSource,UICollectionViewDelegate {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return videoArray.count
    }


    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier:Constant.VideoIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! CollectionListViewCell
        cell.label1CollectionList.text = videoArray[indexPath.row].title ?? ""
        cell.label2CollectionList.text = videoArray[indexPath.row].shortTitle
        cell.label3CollectionList.text = "\(videoArray[indexPath.row].rating)"

        ***cell.imageCollectionList.sd_setImage(with: URL(string:post[indexPath.row].thumbnail), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "placeholder.png"))
//        cell.label3CollectionList.sd(videoArray[indexPath.row].thumbnail)
        return cell***
    }




    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    
   
        return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.width/2, height: collectionView.frame.height)
    }


}
```

This is collectionListViewCell:

```
import UIKit
import SDWebImage

class CollectionListViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    //    var listArray : [Video] = []

    @IBOutlet weak var label3CollectionList: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var label2CollectionList: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var label1CollectionList: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var imageCollectionList: UIImageView!
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        imageCollectionList.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 10, height: 10)
        imageCollectionList.layer.shadowRadius = 10
        imageCollectionList.layer.masksToBounds = true
    
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question. But i think your proble is that sd_setImage accepts one item and you need to pass an array?

And can you share your CollectionListViewCell?

Comment: Added collectionListViewCell. Where do i need the array of elements? Thanks

Comment: No, it seems you don't need it. I misunderstood the question.

But I cant understand the issue. What do you mean with "create" the collectionlist?

You already have a imageCollectionView in your cell and you are already calling the async load of the image.

What are you trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to show some images in horizontal scroll view. This image has 3 labels on it taking info from apiServer, and image is given through thumbnail from server

Comment: Yeah I got that part, what I can't see is the problem.
Once you import the framework, calling the sd_setImage will do what do you want (or load a placeholder if can't get an image).
So this is not happening? you are getting an error? syntax error? compiler error? runtime error?

When you say "I do not know how to create cell.imageCollectionList", what do you mean? you already created the image in the cell.

Comment: Once i Import framework i want to show the image in cell. The error i am getting right now is " Cannot convert value of type 'String?' to expected argument type 'URL?'"... When i said i did know how to crear a image in cell is just why i am not able to show image in cell, but i have already shown labels and horizontal scrollView i am seeing now in when i build the project.

Comment: What is the input parameter type in sd_image ?. If String? You could add « .absoluteString » after URL(…) to get the String representation of URL